# Returning true or false if a certain string is found

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am having some issues programming this function. Because it doesn't seem to work for me.

What it's supposed to do is:

1. Search a string using an array as needles
2. If the string is found return true and stop
3. If not found continue the search until it's found
4. If it doesn't exist within an array return false

The problem is that every time it doesn't have a match it returns 'NOT FOUND' so i get 'NOT FOUND' printed a few times.
 If it does find anything it prints 'FOUND' a few times and 'NOT FOUND' a few times as well because some array elements don't match.
How can i make it possible so that if it does find a string it returns ONLY 1 'FOUND' and if it doesn't find anything it returns ONLY 1 'NOT FOUND'.

 CODE:

```
function check($hay, $array) {
        foreach ($array as $array_element)
            if (stripos($hay, $array_element)) {
              echo "FOUND";
        } else {
            echo "NOT FOUND";
        }
}
```

Example output:

```
NOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUND
```

or:

```
FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUNDNOT FOUND
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function check($hay, $array) {

        foreach ($array as $array_element)
        {

            if (stripos($hay, $array_element) !== false )
                {
                      echo "FOUND";
                      return true;

                }
        }

echo "NOT FOUND";
return false;

}
```

You are checking if '$hay' contains '$array_element' .

If you want the array element to be identical with the search do

```
if ( $hay == $array_element)
```

Comment: Functions should'nt be responsible for output

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is that your function is only responsible to indicate whether the word has been found or not, and where the function flames choose how to handle this result.

Assuming that your array is something like: `array("word1", "word2", "word3", "...")`

```
function check($hay, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $array_element)
        if (stripos($hay, $array_element)!== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If the string is found, the function stops execution and returns true, otherwise return false.

Therefore, in the place where you make the call to the function is where you should put your script how to behave.

For example:

```
<?php
    function check($hay, $array) {
       foreach ($array as $array_element)
          if (stripos($hay, $array_element)!== false) {
            return true;
          }
       }
       return false;
     }

     $array = array('word1','word2','word3');

     if(check('word1',$array)){
        echo "found";
        callAnotherFunction;
        sendSomething

     }else{
        echo "not found"
        callAnotherFunction;
        sendSomething
     }
```

Still, assuming your array is like: `array("word1", "word2", "word3", "...")`, I would change the function code with the following code:

```
    function check($hay, $array) {
       $isFound = false; // default string is not found
       $i = 0; // count
       $arrayLength = count($array) //length of your array;
       while(!$isFound && $i<arrayLength - 1){
          if (stripos($hay, $array_element)!== false) {
             $isFound = true;
          }
          $i++;
       }
       return $isFound;
    }
```

This way is a cleaner and easier to maintain code, in my opinion.

Try it and let us know if everything is working you.

Comment: Why work with the reduntant boolean in the last function. Just return true when found and return false at the end?

Comment: this is only a alternative, is good for a developer can know various options, and for huge scripts i prefer last method, because i don't like to stop a execution of an iteration with reserved words/functions/constructor of the language,  is not clean code in my opinion, and depend of the script is more hard to depurate, is always ideal for developers to know different options, then them can choose which is the best method for solve a problem

Comment: If that array is containing 10.0000.000 entries and the entry that u need to match is at index 0 you're waisting resources for the other 9.999.999 entries

Comment: nono, check while again, while(!$isFound && $i<arrayLength - 1), when !$isFound is true, while will not be executed again